# How to return String Array from C++ to Java (JNI)

Tags: java, c++, arrays, string, java-native-interface

i have a String array on c++ and i need to return it to the Java class.
How can i do this?

I have tried this:

```
string paroleord[app.size()];
jobjectArray ret;
ret = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(app.size(),env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), 0);
for (int k = 0; k < app.size(); k++)
{
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret, k,env->NewStringUTF(paroleord[k]));
}

return ret;
```

But i have an error because NewStringUTF needs an object as parameter, can you help me please?

Comment: Two things: First of all C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), it's a non-portable extension of a few compilers. Secondly, if you define the array as a local variable inside a function, its life-time ends with the function, all pointers to elements in it will become invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: *But i have an error because NewStringUTF needs an object as 3rd parameter* -- This is not true.  There is no 3rd parameter to `NewStringUTF`.  The `NewStringUTF` function takes one parameter in the context you're using it. Instead of describing the error, please post the actual error message, as it seems you're mistaken as to the error.

Comment: Yes your're right, i meant THE parameter.

Comment: a std::string is not a char*. Use `paroleord[k].c_str()`

Comment: @SimoneCappella That parameter in terms of the language doesn't exist, since it isn't C++.  If you want a C++ dynamic array, use `std::vector<string> 
 paroleord(app.size());`.

Comment: I had a vector<string> but then i converted it to a string array because i didn t know how to return the vector to java

Comment: Chaining call after call in JNI, like you do with `ret = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(app.size(),env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), 0);` is a **really** bad idea.  You're not checking any return values along the way.  JNI is **very** fragile - one little thing goes wrong - such as you miss a pending exception - and things may work for a while, or they may go to pieces immediately.  And when you chain calls like that, you will **not** be able to figure out which one is failing.  **One** call per line, check **all** return values for errors and pending exceptions.  **Every** call.

Comment: @SimoneCappella -- Where does your code return any C++ array back to Java?  Your stating things that do not exist in the code that you're writing.  You're creating a Java array from an "array" of strings and returning the Java array.  The problem is that what you're doing is **not** the way to create a **C++** dynamic array on the first line.  The way you do that in C++ is to use `std::vector<string>`.  Note that your C++ code will not compile if you happen to change to Visual Studio, or specify ANSI compiling options if you're using g++ or clang.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie don t worry bro it compiled and worked fine all i had to do was what manuell suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you can survive with `Vector` or `Array` you can simply return collection from C++ code.

It will require some "low level" coding, but it's fairly straightforward.

Take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-045/

as for the String itself, take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-010/

Also, make sure to convert `string` to array of characters.

```
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, my_string.c_str());
```